# cocos2d-x cant save xml data on Android device

Tags: cocos2d-x

I've got a problem: I used different ways to save my xml data, in `pugixml` it was `save_file` , then I used `valueMap` of cocos, both these ways work perfect on win32, but they don't work on Android!

Does anyone knows, why? Maybe I must do some extra things to let the android device use the disk memory? Please help!

Answer (score 0):

Add `WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` permission to `manifest` file and try again.

```
<manifest ...>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    ...
</manifest>
```